# I have created a lot of access_token with no_expiry scope while experimenting. How do I delete them?

Tags: support, api, authentication, api-key, oauth2

While learning how to work with the StackApps APIs, I created quite a few (more than 10) `access_token` with `no_expiry` scope. Finally I have got my applicaiton working but I am worried that all those `access_token` are out open in the wild and on top of that I did not save them anywhere.
Should I be worried?. How do I access the tokens that I created and delete them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [the `/apps/{accessTokens}/de-authenticate` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/application-de-authenticate) does.

> Passing valid `access_tokens` to this method causes the application that created them to be de-authorized by the user associated with each `access_token`. This will remove the application from their apps tab, **and cause all other existing `access_tokens` to be destroyed.**

<sup>(Emphasis added)</sup>

So if you do not remember a valid `access_token`, create a temporary new one for that user and your app.

Then call `/2.2/apps/{A_VALID_TOKEN_FOR_USER}/de-authenticate`.

This will invalidate all of that user's tokens for your app.

Comment: Thanks!. I tested with the current tokens and validated it with some tokens from browser history.